# How to access drives that are mounted by other users?

Tags: mount, permissions, users

On my PC, I have three user accounts. Suppose I open a drive from the file manager in one account, it gets mounted and can be accessed fine. But when I try to access the same drive from another account, it appears as already mounted, but trying to open it results in the following error:

> You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of “My Videos”.

I know that I can do

```
sudo umount
```

and then

```
sudo mkdir
sudo mount
```

But, is there any permanent fix?

Comment: What is the result of `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/` when that drive is plugged?

Comment: 'total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct  2 18:34 3C18F90318F8BD48 -> ../../sdb3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct  2 18:34 5e89f82b-dea9-4348-88f9-ac5cd533437f -> ../../sdb9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct  2 18:34 648660B6866089FE -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct  2 18:34 8012db19-0086-4576-96a2-34f50a75ecfb -> ../../sdb8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct  2 18:34 88EAB7AEEAB796C2 -> ../../sdb6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct  2 21:23 8AD65635D65621AD -> ../../sdb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct  2 18:34 96C01076C0105EB5 -> ../../sda3'

Comment: alls messed up, how can i reverse everything i did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happen because when a device is mounted is mounted under your name and so, the system think that is yours and only you should have access to it. To pass by this you can simply unplug and plug again that device when you switch to another account, or...

From this output:

```
total 0 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 2 18:34 3C18F90318F8BD48 -> ../../sdb3 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 2 18:34 5e89f82b-dea9-4348-88f9-ac5cd533437f -> ../../sdb9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 2 18:34 648660B6866089FE -> ../../sda2 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 2 18:34 8012db19-0086-4576-96a2-34f50a75ecfb -> ../../sdb8 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 2 18:34 88EAB7AEEAB796C2 -> ../../sdb6 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 2 21:23 8AD65635D65621AD -> ../../sdb2 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 2 18:34 96C01076C0105EB5 -> ../../sda3
```

I can understand that you have probably more than one device plugged. Let's take *for example* `sdb2` - it was the last one plugged. It's UUID is `8AD65635D65621AD` - keep this in mind.

First, make a group called let say `my_device` (you can call it whatever else) and add your accounts to it. You will do these from terminal:

```
sudo groupadd my_device
sudo usermod -a -G my_device your_username
sudo usermod -a -G my_device another_username
#...
sudo usermod -a -G my_device last_username
```

Second, make a new folder called `my_device` in `/media` and give everyone in the `my_device` group permission to read and write it:

```
sudo mkdir /media/my_device
sudo chown :my_device /media/my_device
sudo chmod 660 /media/my_device
```

Finally, open `fstab` as root. Something like:

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/fstab
```

and add this line at the end:

```
UUID=8AD65635D65621AD    /media/my_device    vfat    users,noauto,relatime    0  0
```

Save the file and close it. That's it

The same method can be applied for other devices.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1684055

Comment: How can I do this for all drives, anot specifically removable drives?

Comment: You can't.  Now it's more complex in 2018 with fuse etc.