# What is my username/usermod?

Tags: username

I am trying to follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352752/how-to-access-drives-that-are-mounted-by-other-users) to allow other users to access my ext drives.
Except I need to use my own username, and I just don't know what that is. I thought it would be the name I gave to my own Ubuntu account, but apparently is not.

Comment: open a terminal and type `whoami`

Comment: Find username as mentioned by @Maldini. As far as usermod is concerned, refer to http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/usermod.8.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the terminal, it will give you your username:

```
whoami
```